# SQL Server Management Studio HotKeys

Tags: ssms

In Microsoft SQL Server Management Studio, the hotkeys at times lose their mappings. At random, hotkey combinations such as ctrl + r will stop show/hiding the results panel (this has been the most frequent combination that breaks). This morning the ctrl + t works, but to return to grid (ctrl + d), no longer works, along with the results panel (ctrl + r). While I *can* go in and remap it, I really want to know *why* this keeps happening.

The only answer I ever find is remap the keys and how to do that, but I'd rather prevent it.
Has anyone experienced this and found a resolution?

Comment: *"Has anyone experienced this"* Nope, never. Not in SSMS 2008+.

Comment: It seems that SSMS is not the best product from Microsoft.  The mentioned problem is old (see [this](https://sqlserver-help.com/2014/05/08/ssms-tip-what-happened-to-my-keyboard-shortcuts-ctrlr-showhide-result-and-ctrle-execute-not-working/)), and this week a colleague of me noted that 18.7 crashed (something with Diagrams)), but [ReleaseNotes](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/ssms/release-notes-ssms?view=sql-server-ver15) say that things where fixed (with too many hits when googling for 'SSMS crashes diagrams')

Comment: @Luuk if you post that as answer, I'll mark... that is exactly my issue and problem. It outlines the issue a little clearer, and while it doesn't tell me the why and how to prevent, it does emphasize the reset option first, which other threads haven't mentioned, and was a /facepalm when I did it and it worked, so... x_x
ty ty for the link :)

Comment: @Nyra: I am sorry to say that I am not going to post a 'solution' which is based on an error in a product, and the only way to _solve_ it is to hit the 'reset' button.

Comment: no worries - thank you again for the link :)